# How to find the vertical height between any two points?

Tags: maps, touring, planning

Is there any source in the Internet that allows me to calculate the vertical height between two arbitrary points?

Im thinking of something like the calculate route function of Google Maps. But instead of the trip length, I want to see the vertical height.

Do you have any experience with such information?

Comment: Do you mean just the change in altitude between the start and finish points? Or do you mean the amount of ups and downs you would need to do to travel from the start point to the end point?

Comment: If possible the amount of up and downs

Comment: Is this related to bicycles at all? It sounds more like mathematics or physics.

Comment: @moz I can't be sure but I think that @Roflcoptr is looking to figure out the change in elevation on a route they are either riding or looking to ride. If one is commuting elevation change can be an important consideration. But I agree in its current form this is not a very good question for bicycles.stackexchange

Comment: @Roflcoptr - I agree, this question in its current form is off-topic. Will close this now, but I'd certainly consider re-opening if you made this relate more directly to bicycling or calculating routes. However, keep in mind that on many Stack Exchange sites, questions that are just asking for links are generally frowned upon.

Comment: Also, the [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) site would be a good place to ask about this topic.

Comment: I don't agree that this is off topic. When I'm planning a ride I'm very interested in elevation changes. Plus there's an excellent answer describing how to do it with Google Maps and GPS Visualiser.

Comment: I agree that the question might be not formulated very well, but that is mainly because my native language is not English. However I think that calculating the elevation profile of a route is a very basic topic when bicycling.

Comment: As discussed in the comments, I've gone ahead and edited the question to make it more cycling specific. It's under peer review. Hope that's ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get an elevation profile of a route from using Google Maps and GPS Visualiser, as detailed on [Aaron James Young's blog](http://ajy.co/blog/tech/google-maps-route-elevation-profiles). In summary:

1. Create your route on Google Maps.
2. Grab the link, and stick it into GPS Visualiser.
3. Bingo! An elevation profile chart is created showing how the altitude changes over the route.

Comment: Agreed... very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Does it strictly have to be a web application?

If not, with Google Earth you can simply hover your mouse over a location and it will display the altitude of that location at the bottom of your screen, which would let you subtract the 2 altitudes from each other to get the vertical difference between the 2 points.

You can download Google Earth [here](http://www.google.com/earth/download/ge/agree.html).